# Redirecting to ASPX page from classic Asp application

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic

I am trying to re-direct from Classic asp application to a .aspx page for a File upload. I am receiving following error. Any input of what this error is can be really helpful.

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Configuration Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: The CodeDom provider type "Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" could not be located.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.

I tried the URL on browser and get following errors

> CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Transactions' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

I have placed my system.Transactions.dll in bin folder. Made sure that Copy to local is true and also have Using system.Transactions . But still unable to see what is causing this issue.

Comment: you should bring that page up in a browser on the server that the site is running on. This would give you more details in the error message.

Comment: Basically it can't find that DLL on the server.

Comment: I have removed the compilers from web.config and started the application on browser instead of Iframe. It throws up system.transaction.dll does'nt exist error.